Decomposing density matrix on non-orthogonal and incomplete set of states
I've recently come across the following conclusion in a quantum optics paper. The paper studies the dissipative dynamics of a two-qubit system and presents the following approximation for the steady-state density matrix:
$$\rho_s\approx (1-\alpha) \lvert 0,0\rangle \langle 0,0\rvert+ \alpha\lvert \Phi_+\rangle \langle \Phi_+\rvert$$ with some numerical value for $\alpha$ and the Bell state defined as
$$ \lvert \Phi_+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\lvert 0,0\rangle+\lvert 1,1\rangle).$$
The paper is a numerical study and their result was obtained by diagonalising the Lindbladian (hence no analytics). Now my question is, how to understand such a decomposition on a non-orthogonal set of states? Clearly the decomposition is not unique. Is it the result of a constrained optimisation or is there a more rigorous way to decompose a density matrix on a given set of states?

Which paper?...

I mean the question is more or less independent of the paper, but it comes from this article: https://doi.org/10.1038/s44310-023-00001-6

I don't see how the question is independent from the paper. If so, why you mention the paper at all?! Do you ask about decompositions of density matrices in terms of non-orthogonal states in general? Could you elaborate how to understand the last sentence/question you write?

Yes, the question is about the decomposition in general, also in situations which differ from the one in the article. However, the article was the first time I saw this kind of decomposition which led me to consider the general case. The only way I can think of doing this decomposition in a meaningful way is to minimise the distance between the density matrix and some set of other matrices (let's say the Bell states) with positive coefficients that sum to one (hence constrained optimisation).

In general, for every mixed (non-pure) state there exists infinitely many decompositions into pure states (which might not be orthogonal).

The last expression equates a state vector to a density operator. One of the two sides needs to be changed to match the other.

Right, I've just edited, thanks for pointing this out

what do you mean with "how to understand" here? Physically, it's a convex mixture, representing eg classical uncertainty about which state you're given. If you're asking mathematically, then there's nothing weird about decomposing with non-orthogonal states: it's the same as decomposing vectors with non-orthogonal sets of other spanning vectors (which might or might not be a basis)

I think your expression is missing one $\alpha$, in order to preserve the normalization $\operatorname{tr}(\rho_s)=1$.
The decomposition that you are showing is a statistical mixture between two states. Imagine that you have a machine that could produce two different quantum states $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$, when you press the button $1$ or $2$. If you decide to flip a coin and press $1$ for heads and $2$ for tails, the state you'll produce in average will be
$$
\rho = \frac 12 \rho_1 + \frac 12 \rho_2.
$$
In general, this is only one way to interpret statistical mixtures of quantum states (very based on the interpretation in probability theory).
We use this to talk about noise. The most common type of noise considered is the white noise, that is basically a mixture with the maximally mixed state $\frac 1d \mathrm I$. If you have a quantum state $|\Psi\rangle\!\langle \Psi|$ and you add white noise to it, you have
$$
\rho(\alpha) = \alpha |\Psi\rangle\!\langle \Psi| + (1-\alpha)\frac 1d \mathrm I
$$
The $\alpha$ parameter should be non-negative and is interpreted as the visibility of your state. The quantity $(1-\alpha)$ is the degree of noise in your system.
In the case you presented, it seems a case of colored noise. In this case, instead of the maximally mixed, the noise is a pure state. It's hard to tell why to consider a colored noise in general, but it could have specific purposes.
